# Comment, est-ce que, et le pronom de reprise

Tags: interrogative, pronom-de-reprise

Une phrase me choque, mais à force de la lire j'en viens à ne plus savoir si elle est correcte ou non.

C'est un mélange de *comment*, de *est-ce que* et du pronom de reprise.

Voici la phrase en question :

> Comment est-ce que les hommes font-ils pour dormir ?

L'utilisation conjointe de *Comment est-ce que* et *font-ils* sonne faux à mon oreille.
Cette phrase est-elle correcte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non, cette phrase n'est pas correcte.

Les possibilités correctes sont :

> Comment est-ce que les hommes font pour dormir ?

ou

> Comment les hommes font-ils pour dormir ?

L'utilisation de la locution « est-ce que » et l'utilisation d'un pronom de reprise sont deux procédés mutuellement exclusifs pour formuler une question.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Auriez-vous une source pour appuyer vos propos ? Par ailleurs, la formule `Comment est-ce que les hommes font pour dormir ?` me semble lourde. Est-elle vraiment correcte ?

Comment: « Comment font les hommes pour dormir ? » me semble aussi correct, ce n'est pas un cas où la non inversion et un pronom de reprise sont obligatoires.

Comment: @mimipc oui, les deux formes citées par Valram sont tout-à-fait correctes. Et la première est effectivement lourde, mais ce n'est qu'une appréciation stylistique.

Comment: Merci pour ces deux commentaires constructifs. J'espère tout de même trouver une source pour confirmer vos dires.

Comment: Il y a aussi _Comment dorment les hommes ?_

Comment: @Istao, le sens me semble est différent.

Answer (score 2):

La forme est redondante grammaticalement et c'est une faute à l'écrit comme à l'oral.

Le procédé consistant à faire *intentionnellement* cette faute basée sur la redondance existe toutefois dans le parlé populaire, même s'il est difficile de savoir si c'est le cas dans le contexte de la question.

On trouvera facilement des exemples dans les textes des spectacles de Coluche, par exemple, pour rester dans la notoriété.